# How to get NPM Express to point to index.html, bundle.js, and nested css files

Tags: node.js, express

I have an index.html which points to my bundle.js and multiple css files (the css files are within multiple nested directories e.g. my own css files are in /css/, and bootsrap css files are in css/bootsrap/ directory

```
dirname/server.js
dirname/public/index.html
dirname/public/bundle.js
dirname/css/file1.css
dirname/css/file2.css
dirname/css/bootstrap/file3.css
```

etc
I'm trying to use npm / express to run some middleware and fake some dummy data that I would obtain from server side. This would mean I'm no longer reliant on server being up for me to continue dev work. My server.js file below:

```
require('babel-register');
require('./server.babel');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(8090, function(){console.log('Listening on port 8090...');});`
```

after running nodemon, i can't get my page to show. Can I get some advice?
I can't really move the files, i'm stuck with the arrangement they are in.

Comment: What does _"can't get my page to show"_ actually mean? Do you get a 404 when you open `http://localhost:8090/`?

Comment: @robertklep , I get a blank page. Opening chrome dev tools, I can see that the html is pointed to, but not the bundle.js nor css (so it's literally just a white screen). I followed the advice of eljefedelrodeodeljefe below, and I managed to get the bundle to show (i can see my texts which are from bundle), but there is no css styling being applied. This makes me think my css pointer above is wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your HTML contains something like `/css/file1.css` to reference the CSS file. With your current configuration, the URL should be `/file1.css` because you're mapping `__dirname/css` to the root path (`/`).

Instead, you want to map it to `/css`:

```
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));
```

This maps requests to `/css/some/file` to the path `__dirname/css/some/file`.

For `bundle.js`, its URL is `/bundle.js` (because the `public` directory is mapped to `/`).

From what I can see, you don't need a separate route for `/` because `express.static()` will use `index.html` (in `public/`) if `/` is requested.

Comment: Yes thank you! and everyone else! I've commented out the functions and I just have my current public line of code and your css line of code. I've been looking through tutorials, and a lot of people use the 'app.get...' function. I assumed that was mandatory in order to point to the index file. in contrast I thought the 'app.use....' was just for the middleware to just be 'aware' of the directories (and would still need to point to files via app.get).

Comment: Thanks again everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
res.sendFile('public/index.html')
```

...should just fix it.

Comment: ooo, it seems to show the bundle.js file just fine! But there are no css files applied. is there something wrong with my css stuff? I have multiple css files in the /css directory (same level as /public). Inside /css there are css files I've made, and folders with other css files inside (e.g. /bootstrap folder with bootstrap css inside)

Comment: the index.html points correctly to the css files (i know this because if i run 'node server' instead of 'nodemon ./server.js' then everything works fine (assuming a server i pull data from is running)

Answer (score 0):

```
require('babel-register');
require('./server.babel');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));

//app.get('/', function(req, res) {
//   res.sendFile('index.html');
//});

app.listen(8090, function(){console.log('Listening on port 8090...');});`
```

why don't you use this code according to me you are overwriting the static expression and as you have given path to public it will point to your index.html it self no need to write get function for that and you can point to your css from your index as well. Let me know if you still have any doubt.
Just start your server and make a requestindex.html will be called.

Comment: I've commented out what you showed, but I'm still stuck at my current point - I see the text from my bundle.js but none of the css styling is being applied still

Comment: If so then you just need to see the css paths now it should be in ' ../css/* ' pattern.let me know if it still wont work :)